# SQL issue using like

Tags: sql, sas

I'm trying to write a macro that will search for a text string in a column. I tried the following to debug my SAS macro, but it doesn't work.

```
%let string = hello

Proc sql;
Create table abc.&string. as
From abc.source
Where column like '%'&string.'%';
Quit;
```

I left out the select variables line as it was irrelevant.

The error message is

```
error: invalid date/time/date time constant '%' h
```

I think it doesnt like the way I call the defined string. I guess `'%'&string.'%'` is not the right syntax.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your like clause isnt working can try below

```
    %let string = 'hello' 

       Proc sql;
      Create table cats('abc', &string)  
          as
        From abc.source
       Where column like 
      cats('%', &string, '%') ;
         Quit;
```

Comment: Didn't work - it says the function concat could not be located,  and the other one gives an error that the following column could not be located in the contributing tables: hello

Comment: It did recognise CAT as an existing function though but then I got the same error as the other soln

Comment: I get the same error as with cat: the following columns were not found in the contributing tables: hello

Comment: Did you put hello in single qoutes first. First qoute hello as %let string = 'hello'

Comment: Thanks! That fixes the the issue of the like statement but then the output table name no longer works - it gives me a syntax error for abc.'hello'

Comment: Better to look for some learning source online you have mulltiple syntax as well as logic issue

Comment: There is a single syntax issue and no logic issues. Thanks for your input though. I believe I am looking for online resources by posting here.

Comment: Didn't work :( but I tried contains: where column contains "&string." and that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Use `%nrstr` to mask the macro invocation character (`%`).  This can be placed inside double-quotes to allow the string macro variable to be resolved. The second `%` for the trailing any match does not need to be masked because it's following character is `"` which would not trigger attempt to invoke a macro.

```
%let string = an;

proc sql;
  create table an_students as
  select * from sashelp.class
  where name like "%nrstr(%%)&string%";
  ;
```

Or, just use `contains` operator

```
  where name contains "&string"
```